# How to position a div horizontally based on a value?

Tags: css, html

How to position a div horizontally?

I used "Float:left" that works. what i need is , want to position that div based on a value( like margin) that value is the distance between the outer divs and inner div that is illustrated in image

I used the margin-left but it compares the distance between the previous child ,instead of the parent(outer div)

I tried  the "left" $(area).css(left:  LeftVal); that is also not working as expected. In my case I cant use the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) too.

How to achieve this ?

Note: The 100pxs in the image is for a example, i might use different values.

[image]

Comment: Set the container div position to relative and then set the child div position to absolute and then you can specify the left value via JS, jQuery, CSS, etc.

Comment: Set the outer div to position relative and the inner divs to position absolute. Then you can position the inner divs with top, left, right and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Set the positions as follows :

```
parent(container) {position:relative;}
child1 {position:absolute;left:100px;top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` to position elements absolutely with respect to the parent.

```
<style>
.outer {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
}
.inner1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.inner2 {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner inner1">Inner1</div>
    <div class="inner inner2">Inner2</div>
</div>
```

You can choose not to use float if you don't want the div to resize based on the content. Instead, you could set the width manually for each div.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your replay,we want to use the position:relative; to the parent

Comment: That's no problem, the parent can have whatever positioning you like, it won't affect the children's positioning. There's no inheritance there. By default all have `fixed`.

Comment: The default value for position of a block element is `static`, not `fixed`.